# PDO Query not firing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i'm having a problem with a query not executing in a nested try of my login class.
Basically the script logs the user in, then checks if the user chose "Remember Me", in which case its supposed to create a cookie, and save a generated value in both the cookie and the database, to be then checked on future visits to the website. I ripped the encryption of this key out for testing purposes (it basically just saves the email as a token now, this is for testing purposes only).

But the query is not firing. I tried with and without a nested try statement, with every kind of error reporting on, but it is simply ignoring the query and creating the cookie correctly.

```
public function login($email, $password, $remember = false) {

    global $bcrypt;  // Again make get the bcrypt variable, which is defined in init.php, which is included in login.php where this function is called

    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT password, id FROM users WHERE email = ?");
    $query->bindValue(1, $email);

    try{

        $query->execute();
        $data               = $query->fetch();
        $stored_password    = $data['password']; // stored hashed password
        $id                 = $data['id']; // id of the user to be returned if the password is verified, below.

        if($bcrypt->verify($password, $stored_password) === true){ // using the verify method to compare the password with the stored hashed password.

            // Check if user wants account to be saved in cookie
            if($remember)
            {
                // Generate new auth key for each log in (so old auth key can not be used multiple times in case of cookie hijacking).
                $cookie_auth = $email;
                $auth_key = $cookie_auth;
                $auth_query = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE users SET auth_key = ? WHERE email = ?");
                $auth_query->bindValue(1, $auth_key);
                $auth_query->bindValue(2, $email);

                try{
                    $auth_query->execute();
                    setcookie("auth_key", $auth_key, time() + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, "/", "touringlegends.com", false, true);
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    die($e->getMessage());
                }

            }

            return $id; // returning the user's id.
        }else{
            return false;   
        }

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: `bcrypt` and Prepared Statements? Is this heaven? Also: Which query are we talking about? The `auth_query`?

Comment: @TimWolla Did i do something wrong with bcrypt and statements? Im a noobie trying my hardest to look for the most state of the art methods on the interwebs heh. Yes, the auth_query is simply not working.

Comment: bcrypt and Prepared Statements are great but rare here, I was happy to see them. Sorry for the confusion. Did you try your query in PHPMyAdmin? Did you try using `id` instead of `email` in your condition? The query itself looks fine to me.

Comment: @TimWolla So i put id instead of email in the sql conditional and nothing changed, so i decided to put id also in place of email at $cookie_auth = and then it magically worked. For some reason i can't use $email inside try i guess? Odd. Anyway thank you for pointing me in the right direction, i spend three days on this. Now to figure out how to bcrypt this token :|